# Nginx locations inside location for script

Tags: nginx

I want to exclude specific script from logging, but I can't find where to place it, because all scripts already have location.

This doesn't work:

```
location ~ \.php$ {

    location ~ ^/dont_log\.php$ {
        access_log off;
    }

    # fastcgi stuff ...
}
```

What is wrong with this? Is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```

I have no words, I spent so much time messing with this.

Answer - it works, just beware of underscores.

edit: but it stops executing fastcgi for them (why?)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/911274/why-does-child-location-disable-parent-location-in-nginx