# Why does child location disable parent location in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to turn access_log off for one php file.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    location ~ ^/dontlog\.php$ {
        access_log off;
    }

    # fastcgi stuff
    ...
}
```

This makes dontlog.php to not go though fastcgi, it just becomes text file, not php script. Other php files go through it. `access_log off` works.

I don't understand why this happens. Is it because if new location is found, parent locations ignored? I tired to put it after fastcgi code, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the blog post linked below for a good explanation of nginx inheritance. Unfortunately it's complicated by the fact that different types of configuration option are inherited in different ways. In your example, I suspect you are using `fastcgi_pass` , which does not inherit.

> Action directives are where it starts to get interesting. They are
>   confined to one context and will never inherit downwards, they can
>   however be specified in multiple contexts and in some cases will be
>   executed for each context

https://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2012/08/understanding-the-nginx-configuration-inheritance-model/

Also note the following example (from the same blog), which shows that setting a single fastcgi_param value in a nested block will override all values from a parent.

```
server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    include fastcgi.conf;

    location ~ ^/calendar/.+\.php$ {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/php-requests.log; # If this executes then server context one never does.

        fastcgi_param ENV debug; # This *overwrites* the higher context array.
        include fastcgi.conf     # Therefore we include it in *this* context again.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is information I was looking for. This is quite confusing, blocks are not like in program language. But at least now I can see some logic behind it. Very useful link.

Comment: I end up with `map $request $loggable {}` for this. But it is not the first time contexts mess me, thought I only start using nginx. Documentation is definitely lacking here.